# Django: Why is self. used here?

Tags: django, self

I was just looking into Dynamic Filtering on the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering

It says there

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, name=self.kwargs['publisher'])
    return Book.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)
```

Does anyone know, why for self.publisher = get_object_or_404, there was used self. at the beginning? I learned it so far that you don't add self. when defining the variable.

Specifically what I am not sure about now is if I should either use that code here:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
    return Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=slug)
```

Or that one:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
    return Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=self.slug)
```

Comment: Because `self.publisher` is re-used in other methods in later examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using self here:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, name=self.kwargs['publisher'])
    return Book.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)
```

We're declaring a class level variable that can be used by other methods in this class. That means we can use the variable by calling:

```
self.publisher
```

Anywhere in the class.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand it's used again at context['publisher'] = self.publisher

Thank you, that helped!

Comment: Done. I just had to wait 8 min as you answered the right answer to fast according to the system :D